# Same angular 2 svg components with diffrent class

Tags: angular, svg

I have a SVG bulb-button component which I bond with a boolean value. `isOn`

```
<app-status-bulb [isOn]=false></app-status-bulb>
<app-status-bulb [isOn]=true></app-status-bulb>
```

Then I condinionally add class, based on `isOn` in my app-status-bulb component.

```
<stop offset="1" [ngClass]="isOn ? 'on' : 'off'"/>
```

And my css looks like this:

```
stop.on {
  stop-color: #00ff00;
}


stop.off {
  stop-color: #ff1700;
}
```

Unfortunately both bulbs are green. Because the last component is set on `true`. But when I debug  `{{isOn}}`  the first one is set on `false` and the second one on `true`.

How can I get two individual states for my `app-status-bulb` component?

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes in your attribute bindings:

```
<app-status-bulb [isOn]="false"></app-status-bulb>
<app-status-bulb [isOn]="true"></app-status-bulb>
```

Comment: Did not work. I tried `<app-status-bulb [isOn]="false"></app-status-bulb>`
`<app-status-bulb [isOn]=false></app-status-bulb>` and `<app-status-bulb [isOn]="'false'"></app-status-bulb>`

Comment: can you show `app-status-bulb` component code please